# Why am I getting an error while importing the Scikit-learn package?

Tags: python, scikit-learn, python-3.9

I am trying to import the Scikit-learn package, but it hasn't been working. I use python 3.9.0, and I'm trying to install the package using the `pip install scikit-learn` command in command prompt. I am importing the package in my program using `import sklearn`

I've looked in many places and couldn't find a solution. I have made sure to install `numpy` and `scipy`, and they've both been successfully installed.

When I try to install `scikit-learn`, it gives me a very long error, and the last paragraph starts with `ERROR: Command errored out with exit status 1:` and then the file directory.

Comment: More context is needed here, exiting with status 1 basically means that an error occurred, Maybe include the full error here, or the relevant part of the error. Even if the error is very long, it's often easy to find the error message.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
conda install -c conda-forge scikit-learn
```

scikit-learn doesn't yet have a stable release for 3.9 with pip - see [this](https://github.com/scikit-learn/scikit-learn/issues/18621) Github issue.